# Parsing a log file within a range in Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

I have a long log file (+5000 lines). Here is an example of the file pattern:

```
  0:00 InitGame: \sv_floodProtect\1\sv_maxPing\0\sv_minPing\0\sv_maxRate\10000\sv_minRate\0\sv_hostname\Code Miner Server\g_gametype\0\sv_privateClients\2\sv_maxclients\16\sv_allowDownload\0\dmflags\0\fraglimit\20\timelimit\15\g_maxGameClients\0\capturelimit\8\version\ioq3 1.36 linux-x86_64 Apr 12 2009\protocol\68\mapname\q3dm17\gamename\baseq3\g_needpass\0
  0:25 ClientConnect: 2
  0:25 ClientUserinfoChanged: 2 n\Dono da Bola\t\0\model\sarge/krusade\hmodel\sarge/krusade\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\5\c2\5\hc\95\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  0:27 ClientUserinfoChanged: 2 n\Mocinha\t\0\model\sarge\hmodel\sarge\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\4\c2\5\hc\95\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  0:27 ClientBegin: 2
  0:29 Item: 2 weapon_rocketlauncher
  0:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:35 Item: 2 item_armor_combat
  0:38 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:38 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:38 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  0:55 Item: 2 item_health_large
  0:56 Item: 2 weapon_rocketlauncher
  0:57 Item: 2 ammo_rockets
  0:59 ClientConnect: 3
  0:59 ClientUserinfoChanged: 3 n\Isgalamido\t\0\model\xian/default\hmodel\xian/default\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\4\c2\5\hc\100\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  1:01 ClientUserinfoChanged: 3 n\Isgalamido\t\0\model\uriel/zael\hmodel\uriel/zael\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\5\c2\5\hc\100\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  1:01 ClientBegin: 3
  1:02 Item: 3 weapon_rocketlauncher
  1:04 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:04 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:04 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:06 ClientConnect: 4
  1:06 ClientUserinfoChanged: 4 n\Zeh\t\0\model\sarge/default\hmodel\sarge/default\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\5\c2\5\hc\100\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  1:08 Kill: 3 2 6: Isgalamido killed Mocinha by MOD_ROCKET
  1:08 ClientUserinfoChanged: 4 n\Zeh\t\0\model\sarge/default\hmodel\sarge/default\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\1\c2\5\hc\100\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  1:08 ClientBegin: 4
  1:10 Item: 3 item_armor_shard
  1:10 Item: 3 item_armor_shard
  1:10 Item: 3 item_armor_shard
  1:10 Item: 3 item_armor_combat
  1:11 Item: 4 weapon_shotgun
  1:11 Item: 4 ammo_shells
  1:16 Item: 4 item_health_large
  1:18 Item: 4 weapon_rocketlauncher
  1:18 Item: 4 ammo_rockets
  1:26 Kill: 1022 4 22: <world> killed Zeh by MOD_TRIGGER_HURT
  1:26 ClientUserinfoChanged: 2 n\Dono da Bola\t\0\model\sarge\hmodel\sarge\g_redteam\\g_blueteam\\c1\4\c2\5\hc\95\w\0\l\0\tt\0\tl\0
  1:26 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:29 Item: 2 weapon_rocketlauncher
  1:29 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:32 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:32 Kill: 1022 4 22: <world> killed Zeh by MOD_TRIGGER_HURT
  1:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:35 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:35 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:38 Item: 2 item_health_large
  1:38 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:41 Kill: 1022 2 19: <world> killed Dono da Bola by MOD_FALLING
  1:41 Item: 3 weapon_railgun
  1:43 Item: 2 ammo_rockets
  1:44 Item: 2 weapon_rocketlauncher
  1:46 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:47 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:47 Item: 2 item_armor_shard
  1:47 ShutdownGame:
```

I needed to do the following:

- Everytime there is a "InitGame", it should start a new hash like game_1, game_2 and so on.
- The game finishes when there is a "Shutdowngame"
- In between, I wanted to count the number of total game kills (everytime there is a "killed"), the names of the players (in the line ClientUserinfoChanged n\name), and count the kills for each player, that is, when they kill someone.

My problem is how to do the between. I am able to find "InitGame" by doing `File.readlines("games.log") {|line| line.include?("InitGame")}`, but where I have problems is mainly in extracting all those info in between and adding everything into a hash.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily "split" a line by a regular expression using [match](http://devdocs.io/ruby/string#method-i-match). You can use [rubular](http://rubular.com) to debug Ruby regular expressions.

Here's a starter example:

```
File.foreach(LOGFILE) do |line|
  # split the logfile
  entry = line.match(/^\s*(\d+:\d{2}) ([^:]+): (.+)?$/)
  # Now we have:
  # entry[1] => timestamp (x:xx)
  # entry[2] => action (DoSomething)
  # entry[3] => additional information (2 item_armor_shard)

  next if entry.nil?
  case entry[2]
  when 'InitGame'
    # initialize a new game
    games[current] = { users: {} }

  when 'ShutdownGame'
    # rotate to next game
    current += 1

  when 'ClientConnect'
    # initialize the data structure
    games[current][:users][entry[3]] = {}

  when 'ClientUserinfoChanged'
    # we can here further split our 'info' part
    user = entry[3].match(/^(\d+) n\\([^\\]+)/)
    # user[1] => the numerical ID (as a string)
    # user[2] => the user Name
    games[current][:users][user[1]] = user[2]

  when 'ClientBegin'
    # add yout own code here
    # .. and so on for other actions ...

  else
    puts "Action #{entry[2]} not implemented!"

  end
end
```